# I have generated this data and I would like to plot it R

Tags: r, plot, classification

The data I have generated is as follows:

```
set.seed(100)
n = 100
c1_prob = 0.8
X = matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 2)
y = matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=1)
for (i in 1:n){
  if(runif(1) < c1_prob){
    X[i,] = mvrnorm(1,mu=c(2,2),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2))
    y[i] = 1;
  } else {
    X[i,] = mvrnorm(1,mu=c(-2,-2),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2))
    y[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

I want to plot X and then color in the points using the class labels of 1 or 0 from y. I tried to created a dataframe merging X and y and then plotting the first two columns, and then coloring based on the third column (originally y).

```
df = data.frame(cbind(X,y))
plot(df$X1, df$X2, col = df$X3)
```

This is not working however, and I was wondering if there is another way to do this. Specifically, is there a way to plot the data that does not require me to merge the two matrices into a dataframe. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try ggplots this is the general format from. If you wanna make a data frame and title them then instead of x,y just type in the titles of your columns

```
library(ggplot2)
your_data %>% ggplot(aes(X,Y, color = Y ))+geom_point()
```

Comment: there is also such things as geom_line() geom_bar() and more